# How can i get out the error line text in python exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

Can i get the **line text** from **<string**> filename?

Example code :

```
exec("""
print()
0 / 0
""")
```

Output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/p.py", line 1, in <module>
    exec("""
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I need to get the line :

```
0 / 0
```

I will write it like this

```
try:
    exec("") 
except Exception as e:
    # Somthing like this
    print(e.linetext)
```

I know that i can write the exec codes in a string and read the lineno from error and check the line from exec codes string but in my project i have to launch a large codes with exec, that mean This will cause the files to increase in size, i need another way throw the Exception Please and thx ✨♥️

Comment: Have you considered the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module in the standard library?

Comment: Of course, but it's a little complicated

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module

here is another way to achieve the same result

```
import sys, os

try:
    raise NotImplementedError("No error")
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    print(exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

Comment: Thos gave me the line number, but i need the line text